# runtime error in vba URL access

Tags: excel, vba

This code was accessing the URL and downloading it to an excel sheet.It was working OK for a while(although there was a few formatting problems) but all of a sudden it's stopped altogether after downloading just one file onto a sheet.It comes up with the following runtime error:

run time error 2147467259 80004005
automatic error
unspecified error

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub first()



Dim HTMLDoc As New HTMLDocument
Dim objTable As Object, objElementTR, objTR
Dim lRow   As Long
Dim lngTable As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim ActRw  As Long
Dim objIE  As InternetExplorer
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
Dim i As Integer
Dim myurl As String

i = 1
 Do While i < 310
  objIE.Navigate " http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds     /dog_home.sd?dog_id=" & i & ""

    Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4 And Not objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Loop

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = objIE.Document.body.innerHTML
With HTMLDoc.body

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = .getElementsByTagName("H1")(0).innerText
    Set objElementTR = .getElementsByTagName("li")
    ActRw = ActRw + 1
    For Each objTR In objElementTR

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTR.innerText
        ActRw = ActRw + 1
    Next
    Set objTable = .getElementsByTagName("Table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End With
objIE.Quit
i = i + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

Can anyone help please

Kind Regards
Colin

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra space in url

```
 http://www.racingpost.com/greyhounds/dog_home.sd?dog_id=
```

it might help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply but in the actual program code it is the same way as you presented it.It just appeared here like that.Could it possible have something to do with the loop?.For a few days the program worked reasonably (albeit a bit slow).Then it stopped.Also sometimes I get the runtime error up and sometimes I get a box up saying that I cannot run this program offline,despite the fact that I am online.